# Amalgamation of commutative subrings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings

Let $A$ and $B$ be commutative subrings of a non-commutative ring $X$.

Is there always a commutative ring $Y$ containing $A$ and $B$ preserving their intersection?

This is equivalent to ask if in the pushout square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A \cap B @>>> A\\
@V V V @VVV\\
B @>>> P
\end{CD}
all the arrows are monomorphsims.

It is some kind of particular case of amalgamation but I could not find any particular reference. I find this a bit unnatural to be true, but I am having a hard time to produce a counterexample.

Maybe it is false in the category of Rings but true in the category of $\mathbb{K}$-algebras over a field by removing the zero divisors in the scalars.

Comment: Are you dealing with unital homomorphisms?

Comment: Are you interested in the pushout in a given (non-commutative) $X$ (the subring generated by $A$ and $B$)? In this case this seems wildly false, even for ${\mathbb K}$-algebras, e.g. take a group algebra of a non-abelian group and two subalgebras generated by non-commuting elements. Or are you interested in an abstract amalgam of two commutative rings $A$ and $B$ over isomorphic subrings? In which case, why the $X$?

Comment: what do you mean by "amalgamation"

Comment: I am not assuming that $P$ is a subring of $X$. What I mean is whether an amalgam of $A$ and $B$ exists as commutative ring as soon as a non-commutative amalgam exists. If $X$ is not there, the statement is obviously false, but its addition implies that the non-commutative amalgam does exist.

By amalgamation I mean [link](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/amalgamation+property)

Comment: In your pushout description, which category is this meant to be a pushout in? Commutative rings? Arbitrary rings?

Comment: The OP is interested in the universal algebra/model theory amalgamation idea.  The category of commutative rings does not have the strong amalgamation property. For example, you can't amalgamated two copies of Q over Z as commutative rings.  The OP wants to know if the amalgamation is strongly realizable over noncommutative rings, must it be realizable over commutative rings.   I don't known ring pushouts well.  Does the pushout of two copies of Q along Z collapse as a noncommutative ring?  I guess so.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I'm confused. I understand amalgamation of inclusions $A\to B$, $A\to C$ as finding inclusions $B\to D$, $C\to D$ so that the obvious diagram commutes. So if $B=C$ with same maps $A\to B=C$, this trivially holds (in particular for the inclusion of $\mathbf{Z}$ into $\mathbf{Q}$). If I'm correct this is the one in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amalgamation_property. Which additional requirement do you have in mind ?

Comment: My understanding is that OP asks, for inclusions $A\to B$, $A\to C$ of [unital associative] commutative rings, whether existence of amalgamation in [unital associative] rings implies existence of amalgamation in  [unital associative] commutative rings.

Comment: For an example of in [unital associative] rings where amalgamation fails: $A\leftarrow \mathbf{Z}\to\mathbf{Z}[1/2]=\mathbf{Z}[t]/(2t-1)$, where $A=\mathbf{Z}[x]/(2x)$. These are commutative.

Comment: @YCor,  the op wants the strong amalgamation property.  That means that not only does the diagram commute but also the intersection of B and C in D should be A.  If B=C=D then the intersection of B and C is B=C, not A

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Yes! That's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you for the clarification.